# why ansible become_user oracle does not run user profiles scripts

Tags: oracle, ansible, sudo, su

I need to login to remote host (Linux 2.6.39-400.210.2.el6uek.x86_64) as oracle user and run some sql scripts via sqlplus utility. Ansible config used:

```
 tasks:
     - name: Running oracle script
       shell: "sqlplus / as sysdba @test.sql"
       become: yes
       become_method: sudo
       become_user: oracle
```

But seems like /etc/profile and ~/.profile are not executed after login. Resulted in oracle environment is not set properly and sqlplus does not work.
Error displayed:

```
fatal: [wh1.db]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sqlplus / as sysdba @test.sql", "delta": "0:00:00.002729", "end": "2016-09-22 10:37:31.033209", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "sqlplus / as sysdba @test.sql", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 127, "start": "2016-09-22 10:37:31.030480", "stderr": "/bin/sh: sqlplus: command not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

If I login to the box manually as oracle user, sqlplus works perfectly.
Any ideas how make it works?
Was advised to set up oracle env variables and run profiles scripts manually, but it looks like not good workaround.

Comment: Besides the point, but please don't connect as sysdba to run your scripts.  That's very dangerous practice and can seriously mess up the database. Use a normal Oracle user instead.

Comment: In general I think that setting environment variables or calling a script manually may be the best solution. It's common for there to be multiple instances on a host, and it's common for there to be multiple Oracle homes, especially since ASM uses separate binaries. Are you sure it's safe to assume the profile script will always know which instance and path to use?  (Also, you may want to check out my open source project [Method5](https://github.com/VentechCMS/method5) in a few weeks. It's design goals are similar to Ansible's, but geared towards Oracle databases instead of operating systems.)

Comment: Thanks to your point. In my particular case we have only one database on one virtual box, so yes, I am sure that profile script will set proper oracle env.

Answer (score 3):

Try using 'su' instead of 'sudo' as become_method and pass '--login' option of su:

```
tasks:
 - name: Running oracle script
   command: "sqlplus / as sysdba @test.sql"
   become: yes
   become_method: su
   become_flags: "--login"
   become_user: oracle
```

That did the trick for me, but with Db2 ;-)
I tried to run a Db2 command that requires db2profile to be sourced, which usually happens via .profile ... and forcing a login shell usually sources your profile.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `-i` flag in your playbook :

```
tasks:
 - name: Running oracle script
   shell: "sqlplus / as sysdba @test.sql"
   become: yes
   become_method: sudo
   become_flags: -i
   become_user: oracle
```

The sudo's `-i` option runs the shell specified entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile` or `.login` will be read by the shell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to source the profile via the shell module. Try updating your shell command to this:

```
shell: source /home/username/.profile && "sqlplus / as sysdba @test.sql"
```

The profile is terminated once the task is run, I believe.

You could also try running sudo via shell like so;

```
shell: sudo -iu oracle "sqlplus / as sysdba @test.sql"
```

Per the sudo man page:

```
Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.
This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.
```

Comment: 1st way works, but it requires some env vars to be declared like: ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID which is not good. I would prefer if ansible can do sudo in the same manner as "sudo -iu oracle", running all oracle initialization automatically... 2nd way does not work. failed with multiple errors and advice to use 'become' and 'become_method' ansible keywords. =(